# Selecting substring x.x.x.x from a string field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using Sql Server, I have the following data in a column in a table:

```
NFPA 1: 4.5.8.1, SFM 69A-21
NFPA 101:7.2.1.8.
NFPA 1 14.13.1.1*
NFPA 101 7.2.1.15.8
NFPA 1 13.6.9.3.1.1.1
NFPA 101:7.1.3.2.1 (6)
?NFPA ?1 14?.?6?.?3?*
```

I would like to select just records with x.x.x.x.(.x)(.x)etc that have a period sequence. I would also like to show the x.x.x.x.(.x)(.x)etc data in the output and not the data before or after the periods.  For example from the above data, the following would display as the output of the sql select:

```
4.5.8.1
7.2.1.8
14.13.1.1
7.2.1.15.8
13.6.9.3.1.1.1
7.1.3.2.1
[THIS RECORD WOULD NOT BE SELECTED BECAUSE THE DATA IS NOT IN THE FORMAT: ?NFPA ?1 14?.?6?.?3?*]
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks before hand.

**UPDATE**:  Please check the sql fiddle:

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86b00/7)

****UPDATE #2 ****: No answers so far, hope someone can help.

Comment: `like '%[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%'`

Comment: How would that last returned value in your sample output get returned? It does not match the pattern since there is a colon after the 101 and not a period.  If it is valid, please update your pattern. If it is not valid, then please fix the sample output.

Comment: Just a caveat: SQL is relatively bad at manipulation of text that requires extraction.  It can do it, but because the design of SQL emphasizes that fields should be atomic (first normal form), you're going to struggle with this.  You may have success with `PATINDEX` (which requires full-text indexing) or using CLR functions, but your best options will be to handle this in either a) your application, or b) by storing the necessary data in a separate field as it's own entity.

Comment: srutzky, I updated the last one and removed the colon.  You were correct.

Comment: any update? Does my suggested answer work? Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want a variable number of elements that are a variable number of digits, the best way that I am aware of is to use Regular Expressions. Regular Expressions are not natively available in T-SQL so you need to add SQLCLR functions to so that part. After that, it is just a simple Regular Expression to grab data matching that pattern.

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (String NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 1: 4.5.8.1, SFM 69A-21');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 101:7.2.1.8.');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 1 14.13.1.1*');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 101 7.2.1.15.8');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 1 13.6.9.3.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('NFPA 101:7.1.3.2.1 (6)');
INSERT INTO @TestData (String) VALUES ('?NFPA ?1 14?.?6?.?3?*');

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT SQL#.RegEx_MatchSimple(tmp.String, N'\d+(?:\.\d+)+', 1, NULL)
                AS [Filtered]
    FROM @TestData tmp
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Filtered <> '';
```

Output:

> 4.5.8.1
>   7.2.1.8
>   14.13.1.1
>   7.2.1.15.8
>   13.6.9.3.1.1.1
>   7.1.3.2.1

For the example I used the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of). The RegEx function used here, and others, are available in the Free version.